# Problem with my dynamic array - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: c++, class, constructor, dynamic-arrays

I have a problem when I'm doing my debugging: Xcode gives:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

I think it's a problem with my dynamic array...

My assignment is to calculate the perimeter of a polygon with points.

So, my program receives points (x and y) to fill an array of `Point`s, then I made another array, `distance`, which I fill with all the distances, and then I can calculate the perimeter.

I don't know if it's very clear but I'm a beginner in C++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Polygone.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int numberSide;
    int x,y;
    Point* array = nullptr;
    Polygone myPolygone;
    cout<<"enter number of sides:"<<endl;
    cin>>numberSide;
    float* distance=new float[numberSide];
    cout<<"enter points:"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<numberSide; i++) {
        cin>>x>>y;
        Point p(x,y);
        array[i]=p;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<numberSide-1; i++) {
        distance[i]=array[i].distance(array[i+1]);
    }
    distance[numberSide]=array[0].distance(array[numberSide]);
    myPolygone.perimeter(distance);
    delete [] distance;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually allocate any space for the `array` variable - you are only declaring it and assigning it a `nullptr` value. Thus, when you later try executing the `array[i]=p;` you are trying to dereference a null pointer, which causes your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

To fix this, you need to allocate the array, once you know what size it is (i.e. how many sides your polygon has). You should do this in the same way as you allocate the `distance` array:

```cpp
    cin>>numberSide;
    float* distance=new float[numberSide];
    Point* array = new Point[numberSide]; // And you should delete the earlier "Point* array = nullptr;` line
```

Of course, you also need to free the memory when you have finished with it:

```cpp
    delete [] distance;
    delete [] array;
    return 0;
```

However, as you are using C++, a **far** better way than using raw pointers and the `new` operator is to use the Standard Template Library's [`std::vector` container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which takes care of all allocating and freeing operations internally. Here are the relevant 'replacement' lines:

```cpp
#include <vector> // This header defines the `std::vector` container
//...
    cin>>numberSide;
    std::vector<float> distance(numberSide);
    std::vector<Point> array(numberSide);
```

Then you don't need the `delete[]` lines, as the vectors' memory will be released automatically when the vectors go 'out of scope'.  Also, you don't need to really change any of your other code, as the `std::vector` class has a `[]` operator, which works as you would want it to.